# Is it possible to install Ubuntu Mate 15.04 on a Raspberry 2 without display and keyboard?

Tags: 15.04, mate, raspberrypi

I read at https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/ the following:

> NOTE! There are no predefined user accounts. The first time you boot
>   the Ubuntu MATE image it will run through a setup wizard where you can
>   create your own user account and configure your regional settings. The
>   first boot is quite slow, but once the first boot configuration is
>   complete subsequent boots are much quicker.

Does it mean that setting up an Ubuntu Mate linux on a Raspberry 2 is only possible with keyboard and display, and not possible with remote console (ssh)?

If it is possible, what should be done after applying the image on the card?

Comment: What is the point of installing an ubuntu derivative for interactive graphical use if you plan to use it from ssh ?

Comment: @solsTiCe : I want to use X later remotely. The problem is that I have only a notebook at home and I does not have any HDMI capable display or USB keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a display or keyboard to do the install as you copy the image to your SD card to make the install (as most of the time with raspberry install)

After the install, you can try to ssh to the raspberry pi.

If that does not work, you need to create manually a user. Insert you SD card in your notebook or whatever and mount the system partition of ubuntu mate.

Either `chroot` (might not work because of incompatible arch) and `useradd` a user or change manually `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/group`

Comment: chroot did not work. I added the user manually in the mentioned files (copied lines of my user data from my Ubuntu). Unfortunately my Raspberry seems to not get IP from the router. I will check it somehow,